# Toggle Disabling/Enabling of 3 dependent input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this section where the user can define the filtering of a search result that he/she gets from the website.

1. Price of Harddisk ($)
2. Capacity of Harddisk (GB)
3. Max. Cost per GB ($/GB)

All 3 can be changed by the user. However since there are 2 independent variables defining 3 values, selecting the 3 filter values individually may yield 0 results. ie. `$300 harddisk, 100GB & Lesser than $1/GB`. The solution is to only allow the user to vary any 2 of the 3 filter options at any one time and automatically determining a value for the 3rd filter.

**Problem:** I need a enabling/disabling behavior like this: When the user select filter #1 (`price of harddisk = $100`) then filter #2 (`harddisk capacity = 100GB`), when he selects a value for filter #3 (`$5/GB`), #1 will automatically be recalculated to `$500`. If he were to change filter #1 (`harddisk cost = $200`), then filter #2 will be changed to `Capacity of Harddisk = $40` based on filter #1 and #3.

How can I achieve this in jQuery/Javascript?

**My Thoughts:** Something like a stack that contains only 2 values, in the order the filters are selected can be used. When the user select filter #1 then #2, the stack contains {1, 2} so filter #3 will be calculated using filter #1 and #2. When the user then select #3, 1 gets pushed off the stack, and 3 enters to result in {2,3} so filter #1 will be calculated using filter #2 and #3. However it seems like somehow something might go wrong with this method...

Comment: is there a definite order in which you would want it to override previously entered values?  In your example, after inputting 1 and 2, adding to 3 you have it overwrite 1, could it instead overwrite 2 in that situation?

Comment: It will overwrite the older of the 2. So in the case you pointed out, it can only overwrite 1 since 1 was selected first then 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a hidden div for each possibility.

```
<div id="opt1" style="display: none;">
<code to make calculation for option 1>
</div>
```

All of them would start off with the display value of none, and when their selections are made and they click a calculate button it launches your js function.  The function checks to see which two inputs are != null and uses their values to calculate and display their answer.   The matching div can be displayed by passing the appropriate div name to a simple function like this:

```
 function ShowContent(d)
 {
  document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block" 
 }
```